# how give cvOpenFileStorage absolute path

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to put absolute Path  in cvOpenFileStorage function but   when I write this code the pFileStorage pointer always NULL , what should I do ??

```
CvFileStorage* pFileStorage;

    char XML_File [100];
    strcpy( XML_File , "c:\\facedata.xml");

    pFileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage(XML_File, 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
```

Comment: try passing path string literal directly to cvOpenFileStorage

Comment: please use cv::FileStorage, not the outdated c-api functions

Comment: Do you have file write permission in C:? Maybe create a directory (C:\\tmp) first and try saving in there?

Comment: Thaaaaanks a lot  for replaying 

@Mohammad   I need to set the value before insert it in filestorage , thank you

Comment: @berak yes it works (Y) 

but I found  in windows 7  there is resection to write in C drive  so I changed  the dirve to D:   and it workssss

Comment: @RevJohn  , yes you are right (Y) (Y) 

I changed the path and it is running